# Spring JPA can't search for nested object despite cascade attribute set

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

so I have an object Product with, let's say, private String name and private Origin origin.
Code is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Origin origin;
}
```

Now I'm using a data loader to add some products into the database on startup like this:

(Wine extends Products and adds a few more Strings)

```
repository.save(new Wine(
    "Test wine"
    new Origin(
        "Crete",
        "Greece"
    )
));
```

Additionally, I have a search endpoint where I can search for either the name or the Origin.

```
public Page<Wine> searchProducts(
    @RequestParam(name = "text", required = false) String searchTerm,
    @RequestParam(required = false) Origin origin) {
    return wineService.searchWines(
        searchTerm,
        origin
    );
}
```

and in the wine Service, I create a query using specifications. Putting them all in here would be overkill so just take a look at this:

```
public static Specification<Wine> hasOrigin(Origin origin) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Wine_.ORIGIN), origin);
}
```

Strangely enough, it seemed to work some time ago but now it doesn't. Now, if I search for a Wine with a certain origin, it just says:

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: [censored].backend.model.Origin

How do I fix this? I've seen like 5 different posts regarding this problem and ALL of them said "well, just add cascade ALL to the Object" but I've already done that from the beginning.

**Edit:**
Origin Entity code:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "regions")
public class Origin {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    private String region;
    @NonNull
    private String country;
}
```

Comment: Added. ^^ No idea why you needed that though ^^

Comment: You can't query using full child object, you can query using it's field. To know you are doing unidirectional relation or not ? Are you generating table using hibernate ddl ?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I'm not doing multiple things at the same time afaik. But yeah, the origin Object I get into hasOrigin is non null and has an Id of 0 (since origins are OneToOne so if I'd search for a specific origin w/ id I'd get only one Wine at max.) So yeah, ideally I'd like to only compare the region and country of the origins in the database and param.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks Well, I get an Origin object with country and region set (not ID). How would I make a query where I only compare those two fields? And yes, I'm using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First join with `Origin` then create two `Predicate` and add them in builder and return.

```
public static Specification<Wine> hasOrigin(Origin origin) {
    return new Specification<Wine>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Wine> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            Join<Wine, Origin> originRoot = root.join("origin");
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(originRoot.get("country"), origin.getCountry()));
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(originRoot.get("region"), origin.getRegion()));
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        }
    };
 }
```

Comment: Oh wow, that actually worked! Thanks! (apart from having two variables, both called "origin". But when you rename them it works!). Do you know whether it's possible to achieve that with the Hibernate Metamodel Generator (using Wine_ and Origin_), too?

Comment: `Wine_` and `Origin_` accually they are naming alias of  table name and column name string I guess, should work. I didn't test it acctually I wrote here without any  IDE that why naming problem happend :(

Comment: I mean, it's not possible to write something like `criteriaBuilder.equal(Origin_.country), origin.getCountry())` that's why I wonder if/how it's possible to use those metamodels with this approach. Though it works as this either way so I might just leave it like that.

Comment: I don't have that much idea about HMG, you can explore the doc and experiment https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html